# How can i transform this SQL query into MDX?

Tags: sql, mdx, translate

I have searched different MDX resources and read a lot of materail about MDX selects and filters. 
I have this SQL Query that I have to restructure in MDX:

```
Select Left (hcc_key, 2) as Rayon
From [alias_dat].[dbo].[tbl_dim_responsible]
where usr_name=('John Doe')
```

How do i select a name field from a table in MDX using the Left Function?

I understand that MDX is completely different to SQL and thus can't completely be translated. If someone could help me get a step further, i would be very grateful.

Comment: You'd need to make a quick description of the MDX model -> dimensions, hierarchies structure

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
With
Member [Measures].[Rayon] As Left([Dimension].[Hierarchy].CurrentMember.Name, 2)
Select
{[Measures].[Rayon]} On Columns,
{[Dimension].[Hierarchy].[Level].Members} On Rows 
From [Your Cube]
```